# All CWP accounts and domains stuck on Account Suspended

Tags: apache-http-server, centos, php, user-accounts, virtual-host

Woke up and saw all domains saying "Account Suspended" while I am the admin and domains are all in default account and toggles are all On. Did try toggling the "Suspend Account" button and reload|restart apache but didn't help at all.

Tried "usermod -U account" but didn't work.
Tried Rebuilding all vHosts, but it didn't rebuild it correctly, and added accounts root dir as suspended page.

For now temporarily it's working on my script generated vHosts but after 12 Hours it changes back. Please i need a solution if anyone can help me with this. :(

Comment: Another temp fix... disabled "usermod" by changing it's name in dir /etc/sbin and now tried Suspend and Unsuspend toggle, it's working but i think this'll be temporary. Will add another comment update after 24H.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue this/yesterday morning. All symptoms are same except account was not suspended on dashboard in my case. Just all vHosts was rebuild to redirect to suspend directory which is not even exists in apache.

The only thing did helped is to restart CWP and requested to rebuild VHosts.

But I'm also agreed its temporary solution.

Will see today at night what will happen

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, this is caused by CWP when the anacron runs, but I solved it temporarily(till the CWP team gets their acts together) by making the vhost config files immutable with:

```
cd /usr/local/apache/conf.d/vhosts/
chattr +i *
```